# Jquery Display the value of a tag of the correct data-attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, for-loop, attributes

I need to put in each div, the value of the option I have chosen so that my list summarizes all the values I have chosen.

Here is my html code:

```html
<select class="col-12 form-control addresses_book select2-hidden-accessible" data-target="points_1" placeholder="test test" data-select2-id="1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <option selected value="google_ChIJT-Wwjxhu5kcRp4HTdJvuK84" data-select2-id="20">Californie</option>
  <option value="djbjdqs" data-select2-id="30">Texas</option>
</select>

<select class="col-12 form-control addresses_book select2-hidden-accessible" data-target="points_2" placeholder="test test" data-select2-id="2" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <option value="google_ChIJT-Wwjxhu5kcRp4HTdJvuK84" data-select2-id="20">Californie</option>
  <option selected value="pQZDJO" data-select2-id="30">Texas</option>
</select>

<div id="#recapitulatif-page-new-quote_step">

</div>
```

And my jquery code:

```
let adress = $('.addresses_book');
        for (let i = 1; i < adress.length + 1; i++) {
            if (adress.find(':selected').data("data-select2-id", i).text() == i) {
                $('#recapitulatif-page-new-quote_step').append(`
                    <h4>Adress n°${i}</h4>
                    <div id="sticky-step${i}>${adress.find(':selected').data("data-select2-id", i).text()}</div>
                `);
            }
            console.log(adress.find(':selected').data("select2-id", i).text());
        }
```

If you want to change it, here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/Spyynox/pz2mf3yr/13/

In my console.log(), it shows me the 2 pasted values and not the separate values ...
And also, it shows me 2 times the 2 values pasted (3 times if I have 3 options), therefore, it's not good. I would like it to show me a value per line so that each div only takes the value of the option it is designated.

Comment: `$("option").text()` returns the text of the option, which will be `Texas` so never == 1.  `.data("data-select2-id", i)` will *set* the data attribute to `i`, but it will be (the equivalent of the) attribute `data-data-select2-id`.  `.text()` will combine the text from all the selectors, which explains your combined text - your selector is currently `$('.addresses_book :selected'), so both.   Not really sure what that's trying to do TBH.  Suggest you loop using `adress.each` instead of `i` then you don't need to re-find the option.

Comment: Your output is `id="#recapitualtif"` so your selector would need to be `$('#\\#recapitulatif` - you probably don't want the `#` in the id.

Comment: [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kfpg7a3u/1/) *looks like* what you're trying to do, but it's a little unclear: https://jsfiddle.net/kfpg7a3u/ - note: you *probably* don't need the `id=${i}` id on the dynamic elements, better to use `data-stick-step=${i}`

Comment: Thank you for your help ! I have succeeded.